# BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR has path for iphoneos instead of iphonesimulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, header-files

I try to use headers in my project for the built static library stored in build dir of Xcode.

My path is:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/include/AxUniversalMap/header
```

when I put this in Header Search Paths, it turns into:

```
build/Debug-iphoneos/include/AxUniversalMap/header/**
```

But I built for the simulator - the build folder is:

```
 Library ▸ Developer ▸ Xcode ▸ DerivedData ▸ AxEMP-fvifqrufioelsgevaoufqzbfvzkn ▸ Build ▸ Products ▸ Debug-iphonesimulator
```

So the app can't find the headers.. Why does the `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` contain the "wrong" path?

Comment: What was the solution to this?